# HTTP response status code in case of angular $http call

Tags: angularjs, http

Below is my angular $http CORS call code ,

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:4808/api/User?login=' + $scope.data.LOGIN           
    }).success(function (responseData, status, headers, config) {           
        $scope.CompleteLoad();
        $scope.LoginExists = false;

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (status == 409) {
            HideBlock();
            ngNotify.set("User Already Exists", 'error');
            $scope.data.id = '';
            $scope.LoginExists = true;
        }

        if (status == 401)
        {
            HideBlock();
            ngNotify.set("You are authorized.", 'error');
        }
    });
```

If for some reason my $http call fails , I need to display error message based on HTTP status code, but I observed that "status" is -1 which is not a valid code.

Question : Please let me know what needs to be modified so that I get correct error HTTP status codes.

Comment: What does the network tab of your browser dev tools say? My guess is that the server refused to cross-origin request as a response to the OPTIONS request preceding the actual GET, and the GET request couldn't even be sent, hence the absence of an appropriate status code. That code is OK (except it uses the deprecated success and error functions)

Comment: @JB Nizet , Network tab displays 502 , which means service is not running.
Now how can I capture this and display appropriate error message.

Comment: Does it say that for the OPTIONS request, or for the GET request?

Comment: @JB Nizet , it's for OPTIONS.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think you can do anything about it, except for handling the status code `-1` by displaying a generic error message such as "The server is probably down or incorrectly configured".

Comment: @JB Nizet , Ok , that will do for me.. Thanks..